# Getting a second dropdown list from the value of the first dropdown list

Tags: drop-down-menu, flutter, dart

I am trying to have two dropdown buttons and a Raised button.The first dropdown button will be a list of countries and the second dropdown button will be a list of states, For example- when the user selects India from the first dropdown then the second dropdown list is populated from the states of india or if the user selects U.S.A in the first dropdown list then the second drop down list is populated by the states of U.S.A. and finally a raised button which will open a specified page according to the state selected.

I have made a drop down button with countries -A,B,C,D but I can't populate second dropdown button according to the country selected in the first dropdown and neither can I open a new separate page according to the selection of states.

```
The code-
 List<String> _locations = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']; // Option 2
  String _selectedLocation;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.55,
        child: Scaffold(
      body:Center(
        child: new Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text("Select a Country",style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
         DropdownButton(
          hint: Text('Please choose a Country'),
          value: _selectedLocation,
          onChanged: (newValue) {
            setState(() {
              _selectedLocation = newValue;
            });
          },
          items: _locations.map((location) {
            return DropdownMenuItem(
              child: new Text(location),
              value: location,
            );
          }).toList(),
        ),
              new Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text("Select a State",style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),

                  DropdownButton(
                    hint: Text('Please choose a State'),
                    value: _selectedLocation,
                    onChanged: (newValue) {
                      setState(() {
                        _selectedLocation = newValue;
                      });
                    },
                    items: _locations.map((location) {
                      return DropdownMenuItem(
                        child: new Text(location),
                        value: location,
                      );
                    }).toList(),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              new Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: <Widget>[
                  new RaisedButton(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    textColor: Colors.white,
                    color: Colors.blue,
          //          onPressed: ,
                    child: new Text("OK"),
                  ),
                ],
              )
 ],
)
    )
        )
    );
```

Can anyone help me with this issue?.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use map to manage State base on country and after that you can use that state to navigate user.

following code may help you to solve your issue.

Add this route in

```
 routes: {
    '/abcPage': (context) => abcPage(),
    '/defPage': (context) => defPage(),
  },
```

Home Page:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Homestack extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomestackState createState() => _HomestackState();
}

class _HomestackState extends State<Homestack> {

  List<String> _locations = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']; // Option 2
  Map<String,String> _CountryState = {
    "aa":"A",
    "aaa":"A",
    "BBB":"B",
    "BB":"B",
    "CC":"C",
    "DDD":"D"
  };

  Map<String,String> _navigate = {
    "aa":"/abcPage",
    "BB":"/defPage"
  };

  List<String> _state =[];

  String _selectedLocation;
  String _selectedState;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.55,
        child: Scaffold(
            body:Center(
                child: new Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text("Select a Country",style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
                    DropdownButton(
                      key: Key("Country"),
                      hint: Text('Please choose a Country'),
                      value: _selectedLocation,
                      onChanged: (newValue) {
                        setState(() {
                          _CountryState.forEach((k,v){
                            print("${k} and ${v}" );
                            _state.clear();
                            if(v==newValue){
                              _state.add(k);
                            }
                          });
                          _selectedLocation = newValue;
                        });
                      },
                      items: _locations.map((location) {
                        return DropdownMenuItem(
                          child: new Text(location),
                          value: location,
                        );
                      }).toList(),
                    ),
                    new Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text("Select a State",style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),

                        DropdownButton(
                          key: Key("state"),
                          hint: Text('Please choose a State'),
                          value: _selectedState,
                          onChanged: (newValue) {
                            setState(() {
                              _selectedState = newValue;
                            });
                          },
                          items: _state.map((location) {
                            return DropdownMenuItem(
                              child: new Text(location),
                              value: location,
                            );
                          }).toList(),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    new Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        new RaisedButton(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                          textColor: Colors.white,
                          color: Colors.blue,
                          onPressed: (){
                            Navigator.pushNamed(context,_navigate[_selectedState] );
                          },
                          child: new Text("OK"),
                        ),
                      ],
                    )
                  ],
                )
            )
        )
    );

  }
}

class abcPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _abcPageState createState() => _abcPageState();
}

class _abcPageState extends State<abcPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.green,
        ));
  }
}

class defPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _defPageState createState() => _defPageState();
}

class _defPageState extends State<defPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```

Comment: That worked really well thanks.But how to navigate page "BB" to abcPage() and "BBB" page to defPage() in onPressed function of Raised Button.Example- onPressed: (){Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => abcpage()));},

Comment: Please add some more information. It is not clear for me at least.

Comment: In the _CountryState list there is a option BBB.How can I navigate this BBB to a separate page called abcPage() ??

Comment: Getting this error I/flutter (  536): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart': Failed assertion: line 1579 pos 12: 'name != null': is not true.
When I click enter

Comment: i added just for aa and BB for all other you have to add in routes your self and also add in _navigate.

Comment: where to add routes?

Comment: MaterialApp widget of your app.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195803/discussion-between-azhan-khan-and-viren-v-varasadiya).

Comment: its working but some   setState(() { refreshing problem

Comment: This demo only work for aa and bb value as I only add route for it in code. Read all comments.